# Obtener id post para luego cargar imágenes en laravel

Tags: laravel, imagen, id

Estoy teniendo un problema con la forma en que cargo las imágenes de un POST. Alguien me puede indicar como es la forma correcta o más segura de realizar este procedimiento.

En mi caso creo primero el POST.

```
$post = Post::create([

    'nombre' =>     $this->nombre,
    'descripcion' =>    $this->descripcion,

    ]);
```

Después obtengo el id de ese POST y creo las imágenes.

```
  //Galería de imágenes
    //Obtenemos la propiedad creada por el usuario
    $this->postId = Post::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->pluck('id')->first();
    // Guardamos las imágenes
    foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
         $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenes');

         $img = imgPost::create([
           'url' => $imgUrl,
           'post_id' => $this->postId
         ]);
    }
```

Como suponía este proceso me está confundiendo el ID o mejor dicho me trae el ultimo id y a veces no coincide con el que debe ser y me pone las imágenes en otro POST

Comment: ¿Y por qué no para obtener el id del post recién creado siemplemente invocas a `$post->id`?, por que a como entiendo la imagen se vincula con el id del post recién hecho ¿no?

Comment: Buenas! es así como dices, pero como obtengo el $post->id ? el usuario lo obtengo así auth()->user()->id con post como sería? así Property::lastInsertId(); ?

Comment: `Modelo::create` esta actuando para crear un nuevo registro en la base de datos, por lo tanto hacer `$propiedad->id` o en este caso `$post->id` te estará dando acceso al id del último post recién creado, al menos así lo entiendo a menos que edites y agregues el segmento de código de donde sale esto: `$this->postId`

Comment: voy a probar como funciona como me indicas. ¡¡Gracias!!